# how to run "gradle run" through xvfb?

Tags: command-line, server, firefox, java, xvfb

What are the equivalent directions for Ubuntu?

> On your CentOS 6.3 host
>
> Follow these steps to set up a CentOS 6.3 host to run headless
>   Selenium tests with Firefox.
>
> ```
> sudo yum -y install firefox Xvfb libXfont Xorg
> sudo yum -y groupinstall "X Window System" "Desktop" "Fonts" "General Purpose Desktop" (installation takes a few minutes)
> Launch an XWindows Virtual Frame Buffer(XVFB) session on display port 99: Xvfb :99 -ac -screen 0 1280x1024x24 &
> Tell all XWindows applications in this terminal session to use the new Xvfb display port: export DISPLAY=:99
> Start the Selenium server, eg: java -jar /opt/selenium-server-standalone.jar &
> Now start your Selenium tests. The Selenium server should spawn a headless Firefox instance and your tests should run successfully.
> ```

https://gist.github.com/textarcana/5855427

I ask because I use Gradle, so this is in the context of making a Gradle task, or, without using jar, just the default `gradle run` task with `xvfb`.

Preferably, **how do I run the `gradle run` task through xvfb?**

Current usage:

```
thufir@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/selenium$ 
thufir@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/selenium$ gradle run
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:run
http://thufir.github.io/javascript/
^Cthufir@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/selenium$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely don't want to run a gradle task through Xvfb, but rather execute something within an X Windows Virtual Frame Buffer FROM a gradle task.

For example your `gradle test` task might do:

```
xvfb-run -a --server-args='-screen 0, 1024x768x24' google-chrome -start-maximized http://runMyLocalBrowserBasedTest > /dev/null &
```

Comment: this is a standard approach to headless selenium on linux/ubuntu?

Comment: this just hangs for me with variants on `xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-num=1 --server-args='-screen 0, 1024x768x24' firefox -start-maximized http://www.google.com > google.html` or `> /dev/null` with or without the ampersand.

Comment: It likely IS producing an error that you just don’t see because it is going to /dev/null.  Remove that and see what your problem is.